# looking for direction for easy, affordable movie editing software with a filter to make movie look old (8 mm)

Tags: software-recommendation, editing

I need some direction.  I've had some experience with MS movie maker.  I'm looking for stepping it up with some real software, especially something that has a filter that will take my iPhone videos look old-ish, like an 8 mm aged home movie.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

One of the best tools I use is [`OpenShot`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openshot) [image: Install openshot] in Ubuntu Software Centre which you can install from :

[image]

You can apply effects such as a *black & white* effect to turn your pictures to black-and-white (or there is a similar *Sepia* effect)

[image]

You can also add old time *grain/lines/dust & general old-film* type effects.

You also apply one or more of these effects to a clip

Answer (score 1):

I have looked around because that is a wonderful Idea, but unfortunately all I could find was for the after effects, and a app for the iPhone.
http://www.raindance.org/site/index.php?aid=5349
http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/old_film_look/
http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/iphone/isupr8-a-video-recorder-of-vintage-8mm-film-for-iphone.xhtml

This is some information on linux film editing software.

http://lockergnome.net/questions/166347/what-program-is-exactly-like-sony-vegas-but-free-for-windows-also-is-it-better-to-edit-videos-on-linux-then-windows

I hope I helped but the overall answer no. Not for linux. Unless you can get after effects to work.